# How to split a string into different lengths of chunks by using regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Here I have a string containing `11` numbers. I needed to split the string into chunks of having lengths of `2, 2, 2, 3, 2` and this is the approach I followed which is also I found from stackoverflow.

```
from itertools import islice
numbers = '01234567891'
it = iter(numbers)
n = [2, 2, 2, 3, 2]
s = '-'.join(''.join(islice(it, None, x)) for x in n)
print(s.split('-'))
```

`['01', '23', '45', '678', '91']`

The above answer is exactly what I wanted.

But I tried to get the same result by using regex presuming there would be a handy and shorter method, but it does not give me the expected outcome.

this is my simple code by using regex

```
import re
number = '01234567891'
splited = re.split(r'\d{2}\d{2}\d{2}\d{3}\d{2}', number)
print(splited)
```

If anyone could help me to figure out what I did wrong in regex method, that would be greatly appreciated.

`['', '']`

Comment: Why use a regex at all?

Comment: I specified regex as I thought regex is the best candidate for splitting a string into different length chunks. Is there any other better solution..? If yes, I have no hesitation to welcome it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `re.split()`, you're telling it to *get the substrings before and after* the regex match. Instead, you could use match groups with `re.match()` or `re.search()`. Match groups use parentheses, like `(\d{2})`.

```
import re
number = '01234567891'
regex = ''.join(rf'(\d{{{n}}})' for n in [2, 2, 2, 3, 2])
# (\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{3})(\d{2})

m = re.match(regex, number)
print(m.groups())  # -> ('01', '23', '45', '678', '91')
```

Here I'm also using a comprehension to avoid typing the whole thing, which is not really necessary, but I just didn't want to add all the parentheses manually.